# Trying to use LiveReload, but in Safari 6.0 the extension icon is greyed out for local files

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get LiveReload to work with a local website I'm coding for now, but it won't seem to work. On non-local pages, the extension icon is clickable and all, but for local files, it's not: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6OD8.png

Does it not work with local files? I have it added within the app. Or does it not work with ML? It works if I add the script to the HTML file, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it is a bug.

It was reported [here](https://andreyvit.lighthouseapp.com/projects/80096-livereload/tickets/232). I have exactly the same problems in Safari.

Just use different browser, if you can. It works great in Firefox for me.